# How to get current category

Tags: php, categories

Hello I'm in a bit of a trouble. I don't know what's wrong with what I'm doing. I want to add class to current category. So my php looks like this:

```
    <menu id="nav">
        <ul>   
            <?php $cat_id = get_cat_ID();
            foreach( $categories as $c ):?>         
            <li class="<?php if(($c->term_id) == $cat_id){echo 'active' ;} ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $c->term_id ); ?>" title="<?php echo $c->cat_name ;?>">
            <?php echo $c->cat_name ;?>
            </a>                
            </li>
        <?php endforeach;   ?>  
        </ul>
</menu>
```

I just want to add active class to the current category. But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_queried_object()`, which will return category object.

See documentation:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion in the end I just had to add this:

Answer (score 0):

Put your $c term (in your loop) in a [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)/[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see if the property you are trying to compare the values of is of the actual value that you are looking for
(See below).

I've also added a ternary operator in the place of your if statement, it is just better practice. (Read below for more on ternary operators).

```
<menu id="nav">
    <ul>   
    <?php $cat_id = get_cat_ID();
    foreach( $categories as $c ):?>
        <?php print_r($c); ?>         
        <li class="<?php echo $c->term_id == $cat_id ? 'active' : null ;} ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $c->term_id ); ?>" title="<?php echo $c->cat_name ;?>">
        <?php echo $c->cat_name ;?>
        </a>                
        </li>
    <?php endforeach;   ?>  
    </ul>
</menu>
```

**Ternary Operator**

In computer programming, ?: is a ternary operator that is part of the syntax for a basic conditional expression in several programming languages. It is commonly referred to as the conditional operator, inline if (iif), or ternary if.

```
if(1==1) echo 'true'; 
else echo 'false';
```

can be done in a ternary operator like so:

```
echo 1==1 ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Another example

```
if(1==1) $boolean = true;
else $boolean = false;
```

can be done in a ternary operator like so:

```
$boolean = 1==1 ? true : false;
```

Since PHP 5.3, the 'middle part' of the operator can be left out.
Shorthand ternary operators can be used to match only false

```
if(1!=2) echo 'false';
```

The ternary operator:

```
echo 1!=2 ?: 'false';
```

Read more:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thank you for your help. I saw that $cat_id is always 0, so I wanted to know how would I get $cat_id of the active category?

Comment: Wordpress uses "the" in most functions that require little to no parameters and refer to the current data available on the page. Depending on what you have available I would suggest taking a look at get_the_category(); or if you are using pretty permalinks you may be able to make use of get_query_var(); based on whether or not the category ID is available in your query.